# Error: Cannot create styled-component for component: undefined

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

```
j
X:/rstfrontend/packages/src/constants.js:4
  1 | // @flow
  2 | 
  3 | declare var SC_DISABLE_SPEEDY: ?boolean;
> 4 | declare var __VERSION__: string;
  5 | 
  6 | export const SC_ATTR: string =
  7 |   (typeof process !== 'undefined' && (process.env.REACT_APP_SC_ATTR || process.env.SC_ATTR)) ||
```

Another problem is that it refers to a path that doesn't exist.

When clicked on View Compiled it links to main.chunk.
Maybe a bug with webpack?

```
j
http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:187248:30
  187245 |     n[r - 1] = arguments[r];
  187246 |   }
  187247 | 
> 187248 |   throw  false ? undefined : new Error(D.apply(void 0, [R[e]].concat(n)).trim());
         |                              ^  187249 | }
  187250 | 
  187251 | var T = function () {
```